# The character "not subset" in asciimath

Tags: latex, asciimath

How is the symbol "not subset" represented in asciimath? I am converting some LaTeX expressions to asciimath, but got stuck when I came up with the symbol "not subset", whose representation in LaTeX is "\not \subset".

Answer (score 1):

I would use `latexmath:[A \nsubseteq B]` and avoid all that translation work if possible. LaTeX is much more comprehensive than AsciiMath.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me: `A cancel sub B`

`cancel` isn't listed on the [AsciiMath website](http://asciimath.org/) but you can find it in [the source code](https://github.com/asciimath/asciimathml/blob/master/ASCIIMathML.js).  This also works when using AsciiMath by way of MathJax.

Comment: It is not rendered properly.